# Having trouble understanding Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble interpreting the Taylor series formula. The nth term of the Taylor series looks like the nth integral of f(x). Is this correct? If so, I don't quite understand the meaning of the nth integral, and how it is able approximate f(x) at higher values of n.

Edit: I was looking at an example where f(x) = e^x, which looked like the nth integral as n increased. Specifically, I'm trying to make sense of the division by n! and how this helps approximating the original function.

Comment: The nth term of a Taylor series involves the nth derivative of $f$, not the 'nth integral.'

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the example of f = e^x. In the Taylor formula, what does the n! mean?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like an integral in the sense that you're *dividing* by $n!$ which is what would happen if you took $n$ integrals of, say, the constant function $1$. By the way, @Sentinel135: I believe you forgot the $n$th power in $(x-a)$.

Comment: Does n! mean anything? I.e. Is it an observed or derived?

Comment: That I did. Good eye WB man the notation is $$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative.  I will delete my previous comment.

Comment: @DanielReed: $n!$ is the factorial function. Defined like so: $n! = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \dots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$. Zero is specially defined as $0! = 1$. And as for your edit, I'm sure you know that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$. Try taking the derivative term-by-term of the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ and see what you get...

Comment: I get the meaning of n!, but I don't get the intuition behind why the power series is being divided by it, and how it helps with approximation. Also, I have done the Taylor expansion of e^x; I'm not able to connect the dots between this expansion, and the role of n! in approximation. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry. I see a bit better what you're asking now. But that's why I asked you to try taking the derivative term-by-term of the Taylor Expansion of $e^x$. You'll wind up getting the same series back if it really is the expansion for $e^x$, and you'll see the role of $n!$ in it. The reason the approximation improves the further you go is harder to explain in a comment (and I may not be able to anyway), but I'm hoping the exercise may be instructive to you.

Comment: Try using $f(x) = x^n$, and $a=0$ as a simple example. $f' = nx^{n-1}$, $f'' = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$, $f^{(3)} = n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}$, etc... Finally, $f^{(n)} = n!$. But all together, the Taylor series for $x^n$ should just be the expression $x^n$. So you need to divide by $n!$ to "cancel out" the $n!$ that you get from taking all the derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely symbol manipulation point of view, you can easily obtain the Taylor series formula in the following way.

Start by assuming

$$f(x) \; = \; a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5 + a_6x^6 + \; \cdots $$

Plugging $x=0$ into this tells us that $f(0) = a_0.$

Now differentiate both sides, assuming we can differentiate a sum of infinitely many terms like we can differentiate a sum of finitely many terms:

$$f'(x) \; = \; a_1 + 2a_2x + 3a_3x^2 + 4a_4x^3 + 5a_5x^4 + 6a_6x^5 + \; \cdots $$

Plugging $x=0$ into this tells us that $f'(0) = a_1.$

Differentiate again:

$$f''(x) \; = \; 2a_2 + (3)(2)a_3x + (4)(3)a_4x^2 + (5)(4)a_5x^3 + (6)(5)a_6x^4 + \; \cdots $$

Plugging $x=0$ into this tells us that $f''(0) = 2a_2,\;$ or $\;a_2 = \frac{1}{2}f''(0).$

Differentiate again:

$$f^{(3)}(x) \; = \; (3)(2)a_3 + (4)(3)(2)a_4x + (5)(4)(3)a_5x^2 + (6)(5)(4)a_6x^3 + \; \cdots $$

Plugging $x=0$ into this tells us that $f^{(3)}(0) = (3)(2)a_3,\;$ or $\;a_3 = \frac{1}{3!}f^{(3)}(0).$

Differentiate again:

$$f^{(4)}(x) \; = \; (4)(3)(2)a_4 + (5)(4)(3)(2)a_5x + (6)(5)(4)(3)a_6x^2 + \; \cdots $$

Plugging $x=0$ into this tells us that $f^{(4)}(0) = (4)(3)(2)a_4,\;$ or $\;a_4 = \frac{1}{4!}f^{(4)}(0).$

Keep going in this manner.