# How to derive the Taylor's theorem logically?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I can't understand how derive the Talyor's theorem logically:

[image]

Well, the first two terms are quite easy to think of as $f(a)$ + correction term (i.e. slope times change in x-coordinate: $(x-a)$. But how to derive the other correction terms just by logic?

Comment: Think to $f$ as a polynomial and you'll get it.

Comment: Where does p come from?

Comment: “Derive by logic” = what you can read in the proof in any textbook. It seems what you're asking for is rather how to understand the terms “intuitively”/“geometrically”/whatever.

Comment: Give an example of what you mean by logical derivation, please

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I've modified the question using Wikipedia's definition of the theorem.

Comment: @HansLundmark Exactly, I want to understand the terms "intutively","geometrically" and "logically" rather than just rote learning the vague derivation given in most books which just seem to claim that the correction terms should be of a certain form: $A(x-a)+B(x-a)^2+...$

Comment: @Blue One of those is not like the others... ;-)

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you're using the word “logically” in a way that probably feels very foreign to most users here...

Comment: @HansLundmark Okay, I see. Sorry for that. Hope my comments cleared that confusion.

Comment: Exactly what *I* just said. ”Logically” is something completely different.

Comment: Related: [An intuitive derivation of Taylor polynomial coefficients](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/an-intuitive-derivation-of-taylor-polynomial-coefficients) AND [Having trouble understanding Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205609/having-trouble-understanding-taylor-series)

Comment: True understanding of any theorem is possible only by a complete understanding of its rigorous proof. Any approach which downplays rigor is bound to only add to confusion. Perhaps you should try to discuss any issues you face in understanding the common proofs of this theorem.

Comment: Check [this](https://youtu.be/3d6DsjIBzJ4) video, it gives a geometric and logic approach for taylor polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, there are two ways to approach this question: the traditional, though less natural, way from real analysis, or the more natural way from complex analysis. I'll outline them in that order, feel free to ignore the second part, if you aren't ready for it, yet, but always remember: power series live in the complex domain.
From the point of view of real analysis, a Taylor expansion simply comes from the repeated integration of a derivative. Suppose we know $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ exists and is bounded in some interval containing $a$. Then, we have
$$f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(a)=\int^x_af^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt.$$ Integrating both sides from $a$ to $x$, again, we get
$$f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(a)-f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)=\int^x_a\int^u_af^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt\,du.$$ Under our assumptions, that's a double integral over the region $\left\{(t,u): a\le t\le u\le x \right\},$ so we can change the order of integration:$$\int^x_a\int^u_af^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt\,du=\int^x_a\int^x_tf^{(n+1)}(t)\,du\,dt=\int^x_a(x-t)\,f^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt.$$ Integrating again and again (and using the same trick of changing the order of integration), we finally arrive at
$$f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)-\ldots-\frac1{n!}\,f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)=\frac1{n!}\,\int^x_a(x-t)^n\,f^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt.$$
So we have $$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\ldots+\frac1{n!}\,f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)+\frac1{n!}\,\int^x_a(x-t)^n\,f^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt,$$ the Taylor expansion, together with a convenient error term, if we happen to know a bound for $f^{(n+1)}(t)$ in an interval around $a$.
Now, let's have a look at things from a complex point of view (spoiler warning: if your professor didn't tell you about complex analysis, yet, stop reading **here**, please):
Let's assume that $f(z)$ is analytic in some open domain $D$ in the complex plane. As we know, it's sufficient that the complex derivative $f'(z)$ exists in $D$. Then, we have the famous formula $$f(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\,\oint\frac{f(t)}{t-z}\,dt,\tag1$$ where we integrate along a closed contour entirely inside $D$, in positive sense (that's the most important formula in complex analysis, in my humble opinion). We can differentiate this, and rightly so, because everything is absolutely and uniformly convergent, as long as $z$ stays in a closed subset inside our contour of integration, so we get $$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\,\oint\frac{f(t)}{(t-z)^{n+1}}\,dt.\tag2$$
But let's return to (1): For some $a$ inside our contour of integration, we have the well-known geometric series
$$\frac1{t-z}=\frac1{(t-a)-(z-a)}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(z-a)^n}{(t-a)^{n+1}}$$ (and once again, everything converges absolutely and uniformly in a closed subset inside our contour of integration) so (1) becomes $$f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\oint\frac{f(t)}{(t-a)^{n+1}}\,dt\right)\,(z-a)^n=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\,(z-a)^n,$$ according to (2). And the nice thing is: we don't need no fancy ratio or $n$th root criteria, it's clear from the derivation that the natural radius of convergence is exactly the distance from $a$ to the next best singularity of $f(z)$: as long as $z$ stays in a circle around $a$ entirely inside $D$, everything is fine.

Comment: What is "natural" is subjective. To me the first approach is more natural than the second approach.

Comment: @md2perpe That's absolutely ok, and one of the reasons why I presented both approaches. But can you (from the point of view of real analysis) give a reason why the Taylor series of $e^{-1/x^2}$ (mended to yield $0$ at $x=0$) around $x=0$ doesn't work entirely as expected?

Comment: Taylor's theorem, saying that a function equals its Taylor polynomial of some degree plus a remainder term having a special form, is still valid. Analyticity is related by not the same thing. For that you need complex analysis. That also explains why you need to use another expansion of $1/(1+x^2)$ for $|x|>1$ than for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @md2perpe you don't want to discuss $e^{-1/x^2}$, ok, I can understand that.

Comment: I does satisfy Taylor's theorem, but it's not analytic.

Comment: @md2perpe Well, the definition of "analytic" essentially says that it's the sum of its Taylor series, so the absence of that property certainly can't explain **why** it isn't. While "essential singularity" can.

Comment: How did they come up with it before real analysis and complex analysis were developed though?